# How to skip lines when reading a yaml file in python?

Tags: python, yaml

I'm familiar with similar questions, but they don't seem to address what should be a simple problem. I am using Python 2.7x and trying to read a YAML file that looks similar to this:

```
%YAML:1.0
radarData: !!opencv-matrix
rows: 5
cols: 2
dt: u
data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 5, 3, 1, 22]
```

For now I only need the 'data:' document. I have tried a vanilla approach and then tried to force skip the first 4 lines (second code snippet that is commented out). Both approaches gave errors.

```
import yaml
stream = file('test_0x.yml', 'r') 
yaml.load(stream)
# alternative code snippet
# with open('test_0x.yml') as f:
#  stream = f.readlines()[4:]
# yaml.load(stream)
```

Any suggestions about how skip the first few lines would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, you only need to skip the first 2 lines.

```
import yaml

skip_lines = 2
with open('test_0x.yml') as infile:
    for i in range(skip_lines):
        _ = infile.readline()
    data = yaml.load(infile)

>>> data
{'dt': 'u', 'rows': 5, 'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 5, 3, 1, 22], 'cols': 2}
>>> data['data']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 5, 3, 1, 22]
```

Skipping the first 5 lines also works.

Comment: Thanks to both for taking the time, but @mhawke is right on the mark. FWIW- one reincarnation of the data file has 4 non-yaml lines. Again-Thanks!

Comment: The stickler in me says be careful with calling the lines "non-YAML." In the long run, if you encounter a lot of what I'd call "less-strict" YAML, it makes sense to build preprocessing steps that conform data robustly instead of relying on the ordering of keys in your data. That said, don't fix what ain't broke.

Answer (score 3):

I have camera matrix generated by **aruco_calibration_fromimages.exe**, here is yml file:

```
%YAML:1.0
---
image_width: 4000
image_height: 3000
camera_matrix: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 3.1943912478853654e+03, 0., 1.9850941722590378e+03, 0.,
       3.2021356095317910e+03, 1.5509955246019449e+03, 0., 0., 1. ]
distortion_coefficients: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 1
   cols: 5
   dt: d
   data: [ 1.3952810090687282e-01, -3.8313647492178071e-01,
       5.0555840762660396e-03, 2.3753464602670597e-03,
       3.3952514744179502e-01 ]
```

Load this yml with this code:

```
import cv2
fs = cv2.FileStorage("./calib_asus_chess/cam_calib_asus.yml", cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
fn = fs.getNode("camera_matrix")
print(fn.mat())
```

And get this result:

```
[[  3.19439125e+03   0.00000000e+00   1.98509417e+03]
 [  0.00000000e+00   3.20213561e+03   1.55099552e+03]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I completely missed the point here, but I leave my original answer at the bottom as a humbling reminder.

mhawke's answer is short and sweet, and is probably preferable. A more complicated solution: strip that malformed directive, correct your custom tag, and add a constructor for it. This has the advantage of correcting that tag wherever it appears in a file, not just in the first couple of lines.

My implementation here does have some disadvantages - it slurps whole files, and it hasn't been tested on complex data, where the effect of replacing the tag with a proper one might have different results than intended.

```
import yaml

def strip_malformed_directive(yaml_file):
    """
    Strip a malformed YAML directive from the top of a file.

    Returns the slurped (!) file.
    """
    lines = list(yaml_file)
    first_line = lines[0]
    if first_line.startswith('%') and ":" in first_line:
       return "\n".join(lines[1:])
    else:
       return "\n".join(lines)


def convert_opencvmatrix_tag(yaml_events):
    """
    Convert an erroneous custom tag, !!opencv-matrix, to the correct 
    !opencv-matrix, in a stream of YAML events.
    """
    for event in yaml_events:
        if hasattr(event, "tag") and event.tag == u"tag:yaml.org,2002:opencv-matrix":
            event.tag = u"!opencv-matrix"
        yield event


yaml.add_constructor("!opencv-matrix", lambda loader, node: None)
with open("test_0x.yml") as yaml_file:
    directive_processed = strip_malformed_directive(yaml_file)
    yaml_events = yaml.parse(directive_processed)
    matrix_tag_converted = convert_opencvmatrix_tag(yaml_events)
    fixed_document = yaml.emit(matrix_tag_converted)

    data = yaml.load(fixed_document)
    print data
```

**Original Answer**

That `yaml.load` function you're using returns a dictionary, which can be accessed like so:

```
import yaml

with open("test_0x.yml") as yaml_file:
    test_data = yaml.load(yaml_file)

print test_data["data"]
```

Does that help?

Comment: I think that you are missing the point, which is that the first 2 lines are not valid YAML and must be skipped.